# Drag and drop inside child document in an iframe not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-dragdrop

I have a angular app enclosed inside a plain html app using iframe (object tag). In the child angular app I am trying to drag and drop text between input elements like text fields. The dragging of data is happening as expected. But while dropping it to the text field which is also in the same child app the drop event is not getting triggered. I need this event as i need to manipulate some data before storing it in the resultant iframe

```
<body>

<object src="angularindex.html" />

</body>
```

Angular component -

```
<input type="text" id="elem1" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (dragenter)="allowDrop($event)"/>

<input type="text" id="elem2" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (dragenter)="allowDrop($event)"/
```

In this for elem2 the drop event is not getting triggered during dropping of data from elem1.